# Spring Data JPA update a Row without getting the row ById

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to update the table using spring-jpa

This is my Entity Class

```
public class RewardEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "reward_id", columnDefinition = "bigserial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long rewardId;

    @Column(name = "reward_title", nullable = false)
    private String rewardTitle;

    @Column(name = "reward_text")
    private String rewardText;

    @Column(name = "reward_type", nullable = false)
    private String rewardType;

    @Column(name = "reward_for_code", nullable = false)
    private String rewardFor;

    @Column(name = "reward_from_date", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime rewardFromDate;

    @Column(name = "reward_to_date", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime rewardToDate;

    @Column(name = "is_display_on", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isDisplayOn;

    @Column(name = "created_id", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String createdId;

    @Column(name = "updated_id", length = 50)
    private String updatedId;

    @Column(name = "created_date", columnDefinition = "timestamptz", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_date", columnDefinition = "timestamptz")
    private OffsetDateTime lastModifiedDate;

}
```

I have a `PutMapping` Spring boot `API` that gets below `Json Input`

```
{
    "rewardId": 53,
    "rewardTitle": "Reward is Allocated",
    "rewardText": "Reward allocated for your recent purchase with our shop located at ABC-Mall",
    "rewardType": "Informational",
    "rewardFor": "Customer",
    "rewardFromDate": "2019-04-12T00:00:00+05:30",
    "rewardToDate": "2019-04-15T00:00:00+05:30",
    "isDisplayOn": false
}
```

My Controller takes `Principal` object for both *creation* and *updating* the `rewards` table

```
@PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<RewardsResponse> updateRewards(Principal updatedPrincipal,
                                                                   @RequestBody RewardUpdateRequest RewardUpdateRequest) {
```

But I won't send my `createdId` or `updatedId` from my Angular-UI.. So when i try to insert the updated-entity in to the table, using the below service-layer code

```
 public RewardEntity updateReward(Principal principal, rewardEntity rewardEntity) {
        String updatedId = null != principal ? principal.getName() : "defaultUpdatedId";
        rewardEntity.setUpdatedCdsId(updatedId);
        rewardEntity.setLastModifiedDate(OffsetDateTime.now());
        return rewardRepository.save(rewardEntity);
}
```

I get the below error

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [created_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

My assumption is that `RewardEntity` gets updated in the same row by mapping the `ID` that we pass and update only the `fields` that i set and do not touch rest of the fields ...

Should i first get my `RewardEntity` object from the DB based on the ID and then update on top of it ?? This makes the code connect DB twice for every update.

Request your inputs please

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first get reference object using `updatedId`

`RewardEntity rewardEntity = rewardRepository.getOne(updatedId )`

update this object as per your requirement

```
rewardEntity.setLastModifiedDate(OffsetDateTime.now());
```

and finally use save to update this.

`return rewardRepository.save(rewardEntity);`

`getOne()` returns a reference to the entity and internally invokes `EntityManager.getReference()` method. It will always return a proxy without hitting the database (lazily fetched).